# looping a string inside replace() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, loops, replace

I have two strings, the second string, as being converted from an array, containing `NaN` objects. I try to replace each `NaN` with a character from the first string, using `replace()` method. Although looping through a string goes well in a separated function, when I insert it as a second argument to the `replace()` method, it gives me only the first character of the first string. What should I change?

Here is the separate function, which works:

```
function proceed(str){
  var newStr ='';
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(newStr += str[i]);
  }
  return newStr;
}
proceed('ab2c');

/* Output: */
// a
// ab
// ab2
// ab2c
```

However, when I insert it to the `replace()` method , I get the incorrect result *(stored in a variable `result`)*:

```
let ReverseMe = function (parameter) {
  let extractedString = parameter.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ""); 
  let extractedStringArray = extractedString.split(""); 
  extractedStringArray.reverse();
  let joinedExtracted= extractedStringArray.join();

  let newArray = parameter.split(""); 
  let mixedArray = newArray.map(Number); 
  let joinedMixed = mixedArray.join();

  let result = joinedMixed.replace(/NaN/g, 
    joinedExtracted.charAt(function (str) {
      var newStr ='';
      for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        newStr += str[i];
      }
  }));
  console.info(result);
}

ReverseMe('ab2c');

// Output: c,c,2,c
// Expected: cb2a
```

Comment: What is the logic to get `cb2a` from `ab2c`.

Comment: This is just reverse() method I applied to the array of extracted letters (extractedStringArray) and transformed back to a string having applied join() method on it. The result is stored in a new reversed string joinedExtracted, which is 'cba' when it enters the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Due to your comment, I updated the answer to suit the criteria you mentioned.

```js
function reverseMe(string) {
  var chars = string.split('');
  var array = chars.map(Number);
  chars = chars.filter(char => isNaN(Number(char)));
  
  return array.map(item => isNaN(item) ? chars.pop() : item).join('');
}

var theString = reverseMe("ab2c");

console.log(theString);
// → cb2a

console.log(reverseMe("1abc2zyx3w"));
// → 1wxy2zcb3a

console.log(reverseMe("a1b2c"));
// → c1b2a
```

**Old answer:**

If your intension so far is only to reverse the string, you can do it very simply, like so:

```
function reverseMe(string) {
  var newString = '';
  for (var i = string.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    console.log(newString += string[i]);
  }
  return newString;
}

var theString = reverseMe("ab2c");
// → c
// → c2
// → c2b
// → c2ba

console.log(theString);
// → c2ba
```

However, in your code the problem is that `joinedExtracted.charAt(function(str)...` doesn't get any number as parameter, because the function passed in parameter **`function(str) {...}` returns undefined**.

So `charAt()` implicitly considers the parameter to be 0, and thus returns the first letter which is **"c"**, giving you "cc2c";

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, the goal is not a simple reverse of a string, the numbers which appear in the input string should appear at the same positions in the output string. The previous version of my code works well with the input consisting of a linear alternation of letters and numbers, for example "a1b2c":                      
 `for( var i = 0; i < mixedArray.length; i++ ){
        if (isNaN(mixedArray[i])) {
            mixedArray[i] = extractedStringArray[i]; // last iteration: [ 'c', 1, 'b', 2, 'a' ]
        }
    }`  but with the input 'abc12d' the result is incorrect.

Comment: Very elegant resolution. Bravo!

Comment: I did, but it says that for my opinion to be public I need to have reputation score 15 and now I have only 8. As soon as I have this 15 score my up-vote of your answer will be visible to others.